# RestSharp - WP7 - Cannot deserialize XML to a list

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, deserialization, restsharp

I use RestSharp in my Windows Phone 7.1 project.

I have a response in XML format here:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=0b39f4fbbb0489dd&resid=B39F4FBBB0489DD!139&parid=B39F4FBBB0489DD!103&authkey=!AOdT-FiS6Mw8v5Y

I tried to deserialize that response to a class:

```
public class fullWall
{
    public _user user { get; set; }
    public int numberOfFriend { get; set; }
    public int numberOfPhoto { get; set; }
    public List<timhotPhotos> timhotPhotos { get; set; }
    public fullWall()
    {
        timhotPhotos = new List<timhotPhotos>();
    }
}
```

All properties are ok except the `timhotPhotos` list, as you can see here:

[image]

timhotPhotos class:

```
public class timhotPhotos
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }
    public double height { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public _user user { get; set; }
    public int numOfComment { get; set; }
    public int numOfRate { get; set; }
    public int numOfView { get; set; }
    public bool rated { get; set; }
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I would be to write a couple of lines of code to serialize some objects to XML and then check for differences between the generated XML file and your XML File

Comment: try to drop fullWall constructor or drop timhotPhotos initialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to change the default XML deserializer to the `DotNetXmlDeserializer`, like this:

```
RestClient client;

client.AddHandler("application/xml", new DotNetXmlDeserializer());
```

Then, add the `XmlElement` attribute to the `List<timhotPhotos> timhotPhotos` property like this:

```
public class fullWall
{
    public _user user { get; set; }
    public int numberOfFriend { get; set; }
    public int numberOfPhoto { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()]
    public List<timhotPhotos> timhotPhotos { get; set; }
    public fullWall()
    {
        timhotPhotos = new List<timhotPhotos>();
    }
}
```

Now it should work fine!